# ZF(C) and category theory

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, set-theory, foundations

Is there an axiomatisation of some kind of category theory and a definition of sets in this framework such that the axioms of ZF resp. ZFC are theorems?

Comment: If you formulate everything correctly, ECTS + separation is equivalent to ZFC. There is a translation you need to do because ECTS is two-sorted.  See Tom Leinster's nice summary article: https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6543

Comment: Thanks for the reference.

Comment: I think I meant replacement, not separation. It's whatever Leinster calls axiom 11.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, this is a well-known fact that goes back to Cole, Mitchell, and Osius in the 70's.  The relevant kind of category is, as Harry says in the comments, a [well-pointed topos](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/well-pointed+topos) with extra properties; Lawvere's [Elementary Theory of the Category of Sets](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS) is an axiomatization of such a category.  To define ZF-sets in such a category you build them along with their hereditary membership structure as well-founded graphs; there is a good introduction in Chapter VI of Mac Lane & Moerdijk's book *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic*.  If you want a very detailed treatment that includes analogous results for a wide variety of set theories including both ZF and ZFC and also weaker and constructive versions, there is my own paper [Comparing material and structural set theories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.05204v2).

Comment: You linked the v2 not the v3 of your paper. Was that intentional

Comment: Thanks, i will use the references.

Comment: @HarryGindi Yes, the two versions are identical, but v2 has the more permissive license.  (-:O